# Need a way or a tool to await a code block in node

Tags: node.js, async-await, coroutine

The ES2017 `async/await` feature is great. It reduces the pain of writing recursive callbacks. However, I sometime see nodejs runtime warning like `unhandled promise rejection`. The reason is that I have forgotten to put `await` every where inside an `async` code block

```
function action1Async() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('good name async function')
  })
}
async function action2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('bad name async function')
  })
}

async function main() {
  const r1 = await action1Async()
  const r2 = action2() // The name is bad, I dont realize it is an async function. Actually throw an exception
  return r1 + r2
}
```

As you can see from the code example, unless I put `await` at every single function call, it will be very easy to let code go wrong. I believe there is a reason that ES draft community to invent `await` for control the behavior inside an `async` block.

There is no problem for me to write correct code. But I think it will be too comprehensive to write so many `await` inside a code block that I intent to run in synchronous. Is it possible to automatically resolve all promises inside a code block, just like a coroutine? With some static tool or magical JS library?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise.all function will work just fine if you are ok handling your results as an array of values.

```
async function main() {
  const r1 = await action1Async()
  const r2 = action2() // The name is bad, I dont realize it is an async function. Actually throw an exception
  return Promise.all([r1, r2]).then(function (res) {
      return res[0] + res[1];
  })
}

main()
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```